# ZF- How to access subform elements and set its values

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form-sub-form

Good day to all!
What I have here is setting up subform elements and it works fine.

```
//Setting SubForm element    
$subForm = new Zend_Form_SubForm();
$subForm->setName('sampleSubForm');
$subForm->addElement('text', 'test', array(
           'value' => 'someValue',
           'name' => 'test',
           'belongsTo' => 'sampleSubForm',
           'size' => '1',
           'maxLength' => '1',
           'decorators' => array('ViewHelper'),
        ));
$this->form->addSubForm($subForm, 'sampleSubForm');
```

I'd still keep fiddling and wondering how to access subform elements upon form submission, to set its value. 
Cheers and happy coding! thanks

Comment: thanks, $this is for accessing the form via view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although it is not clear what `$this` is, the following should work:

```
$this->form->getSubForm('sampleSubForm')->test->setValue('some value');
```